# View octal encoding for a Unicode string (in-browser or OSX tool)

Tags: xml, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

There is an invisible character breaking my XML parser.

`c&`

The XML claims to be UTF-8, but when I try to use `<c:import . . . charEncoding="UTF-8">`

I get this friendly message:

> ERROR: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.io.CharConversionException: illegal utf8 encoding at (187)

I have been able to locate the source of the problem. It is an invisible character located between 'c' and '&'.

I would like to know more about this character, but it seems IntelliJ cannot show me hidden characters . . .

I think I saw a tool online that would convert Unicode characters to their octal values, but I can not find it again. If there is a tool I need to download that would be fine.

Any suggestions?

---

OK a friend told me about `od` so I gave that a try:

```
$ echo -n "c&" | od -c
0000000    c 357 273 277 357 273 277   &                                
0000010
```

So it seems the problem is cause by the byte sequence `357 273 277`

Do we know what that sequence is?

Comment: Why octal rather than hex?  Just curiosity, though my first step in analyzing will be to convert octal to hex.

Comment: I tried HEX, but it was combining the bytes into pairs and being hard to understand. I have _never_ done anything like this before and tried all possible OD options. the 'c escape code' option was the most understandable & clearly showed a pattern.

Comment: I agree that 'od -x' is not a useful format.  So much so that back in 1988 I wrote an 'odx' (octal dump in hex, or 'od -x done right') program that does a byte-by-byte hex dump a bit like 'od -c'.  I still use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the table below, the dots represent the breaks between octal digits, and the dashes represent the breaks between hex digits.

```
Octal:      3    5   7   |  2    7   3  |  2    7   7
Binary:    11.10-1.111   | 10.11-1.011  | 10.11-1.111
Hex:         E     F     |   B     B    |   B     F
```

This has the correct form for valid UTF-8.  The first nybble shows two continuation bytes, and the next two bytes are indeed continuation bytes.  The second nybble of the first byte, and the last 6 bits of each of the next two bytes form the data for the Unicode character.

```
Unicode Binary:  1111 1110 11.11 1111
Unicode Hex:      F     E    F    F
```

Therefore, the character is U+FEFF, which is the BOM (byte-order mark) or ZWNBSP (zero-width non-breaking space).  It is aconventional to encode the BOM in UTF-8 (it isn't needed); it is doubly aconventional to encode two of them in a row; and it is triply aconventional for the BOM not to be the first character in the UTF-8 code stream.

See the [Unicode FAQ on BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html#BOM) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: it was the [byte-order-mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

```
Octal:   357       273       277
Binary: 011101111 010111011 010111111
Hex:    0xEF      0xBB      0xBF
```

Byte-order-mark is valid UTF-16, so I tried importing the feed as UTF-16 & it worked like a charm.